# How do I define a list name based on the value of a defined variable

Tags: java

I would like to create a list name based on the value of an existing variable.  For example

```
double x;
x = 1.23

List<Something> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add(new Something(Blah, Blah));
```

Naturally this tells me that x is already defined.  How can I make the name of the list the value of an existing variable?

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: I have to iterate over 1/2 billion rows of data in a database and add data to multiple lists based on the values of the rows.  I need to create the list based on a value in the rows of data of which multiple rows of data may use the same list so they need to add to an existing list otherwise create a new list.  Then once I have the lists I sort them and iterate over the list to perform some statistical functions.

Comment: You can't use the same name. You can however write a logic to append/prepend the name of the variable, every time you need to create a new one.

Comment: Then, you will have to use a Map of some sort that keys on something unique from your row data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment that you need to "iterate through several rows of data from a database and add data to multiple lists based on the values of the rows", you could structure your `for` loop like this:

```
double x = 1.23

Map<Double, List<Something>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (;;) {
 List<Something> xValues = null;
if (map.containsKey(x)) {
   xValues = map.get(x);
} else {
  xValues = new ArrayList<>();
  map.put(x, xValues);
}
xValues.add(new Something(Blah, Blah)); 
}
```

Of course the value of `x = 1.23` could come from another collection or directly from a `resultset`.

Comment: Would this allow me to add to an existing list?  For example if two rows of data have the same x value. Would it add both values to the x list?

Comment: Yes. The value of x is the key of the map so it will match an existing list containing data from previous rows.

Comment: I updated the code to your suggestion but am getting the error `wrong number of type arguments required 2` @saheed

Comment: @mithrix since you've accepted an answer, you should leave the original question intact. The additional issues you are facing should be described in a separate question, so please revert your edits to the question above.

Comment: Done, do you know why i'm getting the `wrong number of type arguments required 2` @saheed

Comment: @mithrix: Make sure you balance the angular brackets. There should be two each of `<` and `>` on the LHS of `Map<Double, List<Something>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You could write a `Map<Double, List<Something>>`, perhaps, and do `map.put(x, myList)`, but you can't have dynamically named variables.

Comment: Would this allow me to iterate over each x,mylist?  For example if the values in the list1 was   1,2  1,3 1,4  2,5    and list2  1,2 1,3 1,5 2,5  how would I iterate over each of those if I wanted to to sort the list and perform stats on each list.

Comment: @mithrix sure, you just iterate over `map.entrySet()`.

Comment: I'm sorry how do I use the myList you mention in your code.  For example if I have the list name of x and the values of  1,2   how am I adding that to the map.put with map.put(x,myList) ?? @Louis Wasserman

Comment: The list doesn't have the name of `x`, you're creating a list named `myList` and then putting into the map with `map.put(x, myList)`.

Comment: I think that may be my issue. The name of the list is based on existing information so I can write back to a database later that is why I was trying to assign the same value of an existing variable to the list name.

Comment: @mithrix The name of the list will always be a hardcoded `String` that you choose.  You can operate on it by storing a mapping between some `String` or `Double` or something else that you choose and those lists, but the name of a Java variable is always hardcoded.  Generally speaking: stop thinking of it as the "name of the list," start thinking of it as some data associated with that list.